# Using WMI to get network traffic by subnet for a server

Tags: vb.net, windows, powershell, wmi

I currently have a program collecting WMI data for various counters on my set of servers. I am trying to isolate the traffic volume between on server and a different subnet. Another way would be to monitor the traffic between two IP addresses. Is this possible to achieve using WMI or am I going to have to look at other ways to find this traffic (outside of my program)?

Comment: I am afraid that I don't quiet understand the question, are you asking to see if there is a way to track web traffic between 2 servers using WMI?

Comment: That would certainly solve my problem if it is possible - the servers are in sepparate VLANS but in the same site